# Ubuntu full disk encryption with encrypted /boot

Tags: encryption, grub2

I'm trying to setup a full encrypted disk with a separate `/boot` partition and I'm having some troubles.

I'll write down the procedure I've been following on a Ubuntu 15.04 Live DVD session.

- Fill the disk with 'random data'

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=4096   #ok
  ```
- Create the partitions (using gparted)

  1. Create Partition Table - gpt
     2.

     - /dev/sda1 ext2 1.5GB #boot
     - /dev/sda2 linux-swap 4GB #swap
     - /dev/sda3 ext4 15 GB #root
     - /dev/sda4 ext4 FREESPACE #home
- Encrypt volumes

  ```
  cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512
                        --hash sha512 --iter-time 3000 /dev/sda1
  cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512
                        --hash sha512 --iter-time 3000 /dev/sda2
  cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512
                        --hash sha512 --iter-time 3000 /dev/sda3
  cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher twofish-xts-plain64 --key-size 512
                        --hash sha512 --iter-time 5000 /dev/sda4
  ```
- Open cryptovolume

  ```
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 boot
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 swap
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 root
  cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda4 home
  ```
- Format

  ```
  mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/boot
  mkswap /dev/mapper/swap
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/root
  mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/home
  ```
- Install (using Ubiquity)

  - boot loader on /dev/sda
  - /dev/sda1 - use as ext2 - mount point /boot
  - /dev/sda2 - use as ext2 - mount point /boot
  - /dev/sda3 - use as ext2 - mount point /boot
  - /dev/sda4 - use as ext2 - mount point /boot

  At the end the installer warns that grub-install failed (because the boot volume is encrypted), so choose 'continue without bootloader'.
- Clean boot volume

  ```
  mkfs.ext2 /dev/mapper/boot
  ```
- Mount volume

  ```
  mkdir /mnt/root
  mount /dev/mapper/root /mnt/root
  mount /dev/mapper/boot /mnt/root/boot
  ```
- Update fstab and crypttab

  ```
  sudo blkid

  [/dev/sr0: UUID="2015-10-21-16-17-40-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 15.10 amd64"
             TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="429817b4" PTTYPE="dos"
  /dev/sda1: UUID="...#1" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="..."
  /dev/sda2: UUID="...#2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="..."
  /dev/sda3: UUID="...#3" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="..."
  /dev/sda4: UUID="...#4" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="..."
  /dev/mapper/boot: UUID="..." TYPE="ext2"
  /dev/mapper/swap: UUID="..." TYPE="swap"
  /dev/mapper/root: UUID="..." TYPE="ext4"
  /dev/mapper/home: UUID="..." TYPE="ext4"]
  ```
- fstab

  ```
  #<file system>   <mount point>   <type>   <options>           <dump>   <pass>
  UUID=#1          /boot           ext2     defaults            0        2
  UUID=#2          none            swap     sw                  0        0
  UUID=#3          /               ext4     errors=remount-ro   0        1
  UUID=#4          /home           ext4     defaults            0        2
  ```
- crypttab

  ```
  boot   UUID=#1   luks,cipher=twofish-xts-plain64,size=512,
                   hash=whirlpool, time=3000
  swap   UUID=#2   luks,swap,cipher=twofish-xts-plain64,size=512,
                   hash=whirlpool,time=3000
  root   UUID=#3   luks,cipher=twofish-xts-plain64,size=512,
                   hash=whirlpool,time=3000
  home   UUID=#4    luks,cipher=twofish-xts-plain64,size=512,
                    hash=whirlpool,time=5000
  ```
- Update initramfs image

  ```
  cd /mnt
  sudo chroot root
  mount -t proc proc /proc
  mount -t sysfs sys /sys
  mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
  update-initramfs -u                      #ok
  ```
- Configure bootloader (`/etc/default/grub`)

  ```
  GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
  GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="luks cryptodisk"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID#3:root root=/dev/mapper/root resume=/dev/mapper/swap 
                      crypto=whirlpool:twofish-xts-plain64:512:0:"
  ```
- create config file

  ```
  $ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  [/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/mapper/root'.]
  ```
- try outside

  ```
  $ exit
  $ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  [/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.]
  ```

Did I make any mistake before this?
How can I continue to configure and install grub correctly?

Comment: I feel bad that after getting you to move your Q to the "correct" site, no one has helped. I haven't done this level of work in Ubuntu. But I did look on google for `grub` + your title. I suppose you found your procedure for encrypting at http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/ (which is the first google search on this topic). if not, maybe that will help. Good Question! and Good Luck!

Comment: Couple of things: 1. You mention `/boot` as the mount point for everything. I'm hoping that's a typo. 2. You did not mount `/dev` while chrooting, but you did mount devpts. O.o

Comment: Another mistake is you seem to be using the same UUIDs in crypttab and fstab. fstab should actually use the UUIDs of the /dev/mapper/ drives.

Comment: checkout [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption) guide by an Ubuntu community member. I've used it and it works very well for me.

Answer (score 16):

You made some mistakes, but the main problem is in ubiquity and grub. Basically, when you set `/` to be an encrypted partition and don't create a separate partition for `/boot`, grub gives an error message like:

> I know `/boot` is encrypted. You need to set `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` in `/etc/default/grub`. I won't do it for you, so I'm going to fail and your installation will stop.

## An overview of the process

- We use EFI mode.
- We install to an unencrypted `/boot` partition and an encrypted btrfs `/` using the standard installer.
- After the installer finishes, we `chroot`, make some important configuration changes, and re-install grub to the EFI System Partition and re-create initrd.

## The detailed steps

- Boot from Ubuntu 16.04 install disk (tested with Xubuntu).
- Connect to the Internet and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update the installer components
- Use `fdisk`, `gparted`, or another tool to create 3 partitions:

  - A GPT partition table
  - A 200MB partition that we will use for the EFI System Partition
  - A multi-gigabyte partition that we will eventually use as our encrypted swap partition, but which will function as our temporary unencrypted `/boot`
  - An encrypted partition that uses the rest of the space
- Prepare the encrypted partition

  ```
  sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda3
  sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
  sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
  ```
- Install Ubuntu

  - Choose "Something else" when asked about installation type.
  - Configure `/dev/sda1` as `EFI System Partition`
  - Configure `/dev/sda2` as ext2, formatted, with mount point of `/boot`
  - Configure `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt` as btrfs with mount point of `/`
  - Continue with the installation.
  - After it finishes, choose to stay in the live system (no reboot).
- Copy the contents of `/boot` and do a `chroot`

  ```
  sudo mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt /target
  sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
  # (Watch those trailing slashes! rsync is very sensitive to them.)
  sudo rsync -aXAH /mnt/ /target/boot/
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /target/boot/efi
  sudo mount --bind /dev /target/dev
  sudo mount --bind /proc /target/proc
  sudo mount --bind /sys /target/sys
  sudo chroot /target
  ```
- (Everything is now happening as `chroot` inside your new system.)
- Add line to `/etc/default/grub`

  ```
  GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
  ```
- Add line to `/etc/crypttab`. You will need to first run `sudo blkid` to find the UUID of `/dev/sda3` (NOT `/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt`).

  ```
  sda3_crypt UUID=<UUID of /dev/sda3> none luks,discard
  ```
- Edit `/etc/fstab` and delete the line for `/boot`. The other entries are correct.
- Install grub to the EFI System Partition, generate a new grub.cfg, and prepare initrd.

  ```
  sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory /boot/efi --bootloader=ubuntu --boot-directory=/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu --recheck
  sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub/grub.cfg
  sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
  ```
- **Optional double-check:** Double-check that `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub/grub.cfg` contains lines that include `insmod luks`, `cryptomount -u <UUID>`, the correct boot entries, etc. And double-check that your initrd contains the `cryptsetup` binary. If these things are missing, it is because grub-mkconfig and/or update-initrd couldn't figure out how the volumes that you've mounted or specified in fstab relate to the encrypted volume in crypttab. (There's a lot of magic autoconfiguration that they do.) This may happen if you diverge from this guide by, for example, using ZFS or by trying to partition sda3_crypt.
- **(If using ZFS instead of btrfs)** grub-mkconfig and update-initrd won't recognize ZFS. The workaround involves (during chroot, prior to grub-mkconfig/update-initrd) editing `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` to add `|| true` to line 139 (which starts with `GRUB_DEVICE=`), adding `GRUB_DEVICE="/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt"` to `/etc/default/grub`, creating file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/conf-hooks.d/forcecryptsetup` with contents `export CRYPTSETUP=y` and file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot` with contents `target=sda3_crypt,source=UUID=<UUID of sda3>,key=none,discard`. All of this is in addition to steps that you would take if you were not encrypting the ZFS partiion (like installing zfs userspace utils in both the live system and during chroot and deleting the line that mounts `/` in fstab).
- Exit chroot and reboot into your new system

  ```
  exit
  sudo umount /target/boot/efi
  sudo umount /target/dev
  sudo umount /target/proc
  sudo umount /target/sys
  sudo umount /target
  sudo reboot
  ```
- You should see grub asking for your password. Then you'll get the boot menu. After choosing Ubuntu you'll be asked for your password again. Then you'll be in your system. Read more about [how Ubuntu uses BTRFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs).
- *TODO*: Create encrypted swap (hint: it involves editing crypttab, fstab, and re-running `update-initrd`).
- *TODO*: Save your password so you only need to enter it once into grub. This is detailed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725164601/http://missinglink.xyz:80/security/tutorial-debianubuntu-full-disk-encryption-luks-fde-including-encrypted-boot/improved-full-disk-encryption-add-luks-key-file-initrdinitramfs).

## Upgrades

- Every time you install a new kernel, you should run the custom `grub-mkconfig` command.
- Every time you update grub, you should run the custom `grub-install`command.

## Other notes

- It's tempting to create a single encrypted volume and partition it to create the swap partition (and possibly others), but this does not work. Both grub-mkconfig and update-initrd will misbehave. However, I haven't tried LVM.
- It may be tempting to use a [swapfile on top of btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_swap_files.3F), but it's probably a bad idea because of performance.

Comment: Just clarifying what I think you already know (per your comment): `fstab` and `crypttab` are actually *not* correct in the question. `crypttab` should point to the `uuid` of the raw `/dev/sdxY` devices; `fstab` should point to the opened crypt devices at `/dev/mapper/label`.

Comment: Thank you for making this answer, it helped me set this up.

Comment: I actually don't consider any of this true FDE, since there is partition information leaked. True FDE is having all sectors be encrypted data (with the exception of the LUKS header at the beginning, though that's technically not needed by using a detached header).  I do FDE using LVM inside LUKS, so it definitely works and can be nicer if you need to change partition/volume sizes later on. Here's an [old blog post](https://archimedesden.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/luks-full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu-12-04-using-the-ubiquity-installer/) on doing this in 12.04, but should work in later versions.

Comment: Also, using a swapfile on BTRFS is **definitely** a [bad idea](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_swap_files.3F)...

Comment: In your `grub-install` instruction, you have a `--bootloader=ubuntu` parameter. I cannot seem to find that argument in either [Ubuntu's](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/grub-install.8.html) or [GNU's](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf) manuals. Could you clarify what it does or where it s documented?

Comment: @SamuelHarmer It looks like they removed it. I think it just set the directory name, and was redundant to `boot-directory`. I don't use Ubuntu anymore. I use Manjaro and it sets up encrypted boot automatically. If there's anything that needs to be updated about this guide, please test it out and then propose an edit.

Comment: @crass Linux 5.0 supports btrfs swapfiles.