# How can I encrypt my hard drive?

Tags: encryption

I am running 16.04 and I want to encrypt my computer. How can I do that?

I haven't had much luck searching online.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation provided for every version of Ubuntu after 12.10.

The official document states:

> *During installation, check the checkbox “Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security*

There is a good guide on eCryptfs [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html)

Here are the quoted instructions:

> First, install the necessary packages. From a terminal prompt enter:
>
> `sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils`
>
> Now mount the partition to be encrypted:
>
> `sudo mount -t ecryptfs /srv /srv`
>
> You will then be prompted for some details on how ecryptfs should encrypt the data.
>
> To test that files placed in /srv are indeed encrypted copy the /etc/default folder to /srv:
>
> `sudo cp -r /etc/default /srv`
>
> Now unmount /srv, and try to view a file:
>
> `sudo umount /srv`
>
> `cat /srv/default/cron`
>
> Remounting /srv using ecryptfs will make the data viewable once again.

You can find information here (some are old, but relevant):

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto
- https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/11/privacy-ubuntu-1210-full-disk-encryption
- http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu
- [Ubuntu full disk encryption with encrypted /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729673/ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-with-encrypted-boot)
- [Enable disk encryption after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation)
- https://utappia.org/2016/03/23/how-to-do-a-full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu-installation/

And many more resources found via Google.

Comment: What can I do now that Ubuntu is already installed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "encrypt OS" option when installing Ubuntu but I've ran into errors with Nvidia video drivers trying to do that. But this will probably work if you aren't trying to use 3rd party drivers.

You can also use the "encrypt home directory" option when installing Ubuntu. I'm using this currently and I haven't had any issues.

Also there's a program called encfs which works well for encrypting folders. Install it using `sudo apt-get install encfs` and learn how to use it by typing `man encfs`

Comment: You mentioned I can do those things when installing Ubuntu. Is there anything I can do if Ubuntu is already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VeraCrypt ?

https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html

> ```
> Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
> Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
> Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed (pre-boot authentication).
> Encryption is automatic, real-time(on-the-fly) and transparent.
> Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.
> Encryption can be hardware-accelerated on modern processors.
> Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password: Hidden volume (steganography) and hidden
> ```
>
> operating system.
>       More information about the features of VeraCrypt may be found in the documentation

I haven't tried the below links, but it should help

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-veracrypt-ubuntu-16-04-16-10

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY83PuG4uLE