# LUKS without a boot partition

Tags: boot, grub2, luks

I remember reading a blog entry that someone at Canonical was working on making LUKS work without a boot partition for 17.04.  However when I did a fresh install of 17.10 I was unable to find anything.  I know that it is possible to make grub handle LUKS encryption, and could probably hack it up myself, but does anyone know what happened to said work?  I searched for a while and failed to find the blog entry.

Comment: as I understand it, the boot partition is required for the BIOS/EFI to load and launch grub, since the firmware can not decrypt the disk.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're running an EFI system, the EFI System Partition (usually the first partition on your disk, mounted at `/boot/efi`) will *always* need to be decrypted so that your system can actually load into GRUB.

However, you can now stick `/boot` itself inside LUKS. A guide for that is available [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/801394/208574) on the site, however this has a few caveats:

- Every time you update your kernel/GRUB, you will need to "re-install" it on your system, and make sure things recognize it. As far as I can tell, there's no automated hook.
- GRUB won't be taking over LUKS entirely. If I remember correctly, it'll prompt for the password and go from there, but it will not replace LUKS.
- This setup, as far as I can tell, has a very decent potential to break in potentially amazing ways.

To be honest, there's little to no reason to actually stick `/boot` inside of LUKS. It just causes quite a bit of unnecessary pain and makes one's life much worse for not too much of a gain. The main risk (tampering with the kernel) can easily be mitigated by [using Secure Boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot) to sign the kernel and any modules. If you want to run this digital signature enforcement, *please* read through the entire wiki page linked.

Comment: In fact I am using BIOS and need to load self-compiled kernel modules, so I am steering clear of secure boot for now. But what I was actually looking for was information about what had happened to the plans I seem to recall to make single partition (probably excluding a mini-partition for grub) a supported option.  And the main advantage I see would be an end to updates aborting because of full /boot partitions.