# Can't get Ubuntu to boot from LUKS / LVM group on external drive on iMac with refind

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lvm, luks

I have a 2017 iMac and am trying to install Ubuntu on an external USB3 drive. The external drive has a GPT partition table (no hybrid MBR) and is partitioned like so:

```
/dev/sda1: EFI partition
/dev/sda2: Windows-To-Go partition
/dev/sda3: ext4 Linux boot partition
/dev/sda4: LUKS / LVM partition
/dev/sda5: extra partition, not currently being used
```

The LVM group that's available once the LUKS partition is decrypted contains an ext4 partition intended to be the main partition for my linux system, and a swap partition.

I'm using refind on my mac to facilitate booting these different operating systems.

When I installed Ubuntu, I made sure all of my partitions were already decrypted and mounted, I picked manual disk setup in the installer (as I didn't want it to blow away my whole external disk including the Windows installation) and manually specified the following:

1. `/boot` as the mount point for `/dev/sda3`
2. `/` as the mount point for the main ext4 partition in my LVM group
3. grub should be installed to `/dev/sda3`

The installer finished without errors. When I reboot, however, I have two options for how to boot this Ubuntu installation, and neither one works.

I can boot from a grub bootloader installed in the EFI partition of my internal hard drive. Note that I did *not* want Linux or any other operating system adding their bootloader to this drive. I just want it to remain a normal macOS drive with the addition of refind. Nonetheless, if I boot from it using refind, it shows the Ubuntu logo before dropping me to an `(initramfs)` prompt with no error messages at all.

If I pick the bootloader I specified should be installed to `/dev/sda3`, it starts loading, fails with the following errors:

```
mount: can't find /root in /etc/fstab
...
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
(repeats four more times)
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

...and then drops me to a `(initramfs)` prompt.

I have no idea how to fix this! I tried using Boot-Repair but it made no difference at all. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working! Thanks largely to [this answer for another encryption related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/801394/643483). I didn't end up encrypting my boot partition as I didn't think it was necessary, but there were a few key things I did differently from above. It seems the major issue was that the Ubuntu installer couldn't figure out exactly how my partitions were set up, so it was necessary to `chroot` into the new linux install, make some changes that indicate what's going on, and then reinstall grub. Here's what I did:

1. I formatted /dev/sda3 as ext2. (Not sure if that was important.)
2. When installing, I specified that the bootloader should be installed to `/dev/sda` not `/dev/sda3`
3. I specified `/dev/sda1` as EFI Boot Partition
4. After installation finished successfully, I told it not to reboot, and I did the following in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_linux_lvm_partition /target
   sudo mount /dev/sda3 /target/boot
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /target/boot/efi
   sudo mount --bind /dev /target/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /target/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /target/sys
   sudo chroot /target
   ```
5. Now that I `chroot`'ed into my installation, I edited `/etc/default/grub` and added the line:

   ```
   GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
   ```
6. Got the UUID of my various partitions using `blkid`
7. Added a line to `/etc/crypttab`:

   ```
   my_luks_partition_name UUID=<UUID of /dev/sda4> none luks,discard
   ```
8. `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory /boot/efi --bootloader=ubuntu --boot-directory=/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu --recheck`
9. `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`
10. `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`

I noticed it was important to get the name of the LUKS partition correct, otherwise there would be errors when running `update-initramfs`.

This took me two whole days of hair pulling frustration to figure out. I only hope that this information will help someone else do it too without nearly so much agony.