# The process of full disk encryption during installation and manual partitioning

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I am going to install Linux and do a full disk encryption, I did some research and want to confirm that following information is correct:

1. We first have the raw hdd
2. Then we create partition table on it
3. Then we create a /boot partition leaving the rest free space
4. Then we use the free space as physical volume for encryption (encryption method = dm-crypt)
5. Then we create logical volume group out of this encrypted volume (so that we only have one pass phrase )
6. Then create logical volume out of this logical volume group (root, swap, home )
7. And configure these logical  volumes (root, swap, home)
8. Finally write changes to disk

Am I correct? Is this a possible procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Dual Ubuntu Installations with Whole Disk Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264416/dual-ubuntu-installations-with-whole-disk-encryption/727079#727079). It describes how to add a secondary installation into the LUKS container created by an initial Ubuntu installation, but you'll find the necessary details in there for your scenario.

(I would have added this as a comment but don't have enough of reputation yet).